# How to use a message resource file in a precompiled library for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, translation

I'm building a library for the BlackBerry, which needs to have several strings in it using the messages.rrc and messages.rrh files to create the MessagesResource interface to allow access.

The catch is, everything being done on the command line, I'm using RAPC to generate the messages, and a standard java compiler to build the library itself.  RAPC generates the MessagesResource class just fine, and I can use it to compile the rest of the library with.  But how do I get the actual messages (stored in a COD file) to come with the library?  Do I just stick the COD in the jar?  Does it have to be a separate file?  Is it folly to think I can even do this?

Comment: Kudos to you, sir. You have found a programming question so obscure that the SO community doesn't have the expertise to answer it. :D

Comment: oh, sad.  And I was hoping a bounty might help

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear.  You want a reusable jar file, that includes the code rapc generates from the rrc and rrh files?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.  Not so unclear after all.

Comment: @Ed Marty  Do you want help or do you just want to be snarky?

Comment: You said it was unclear, then stated exactly what I was asking in your own words.  You obviously know what I'm asking.  Do you have an answer or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, never found an answer to this.  Had to move to a proprietary way of fetching strings from a resource file included with the project instead.  A shame.